# JIRA - Creating an issue from the workflow of another issue type

Tags: workflow, jira, issue-tracking

I'm working for first time with JIRA. I'm designing the workflow of my issue with the WorkflowDesigner. I want to create an issue from another issue-type inside one of the states of the workflow.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!!!

Juan

Answer (score 1):

Search for custom postfunctions that create subtasks and use that idea to create another issue of another type. Changing the issue type of the current issue is much harder and not recommended.

~Matt